# Changing image in an xml page on button click.. android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a 2 spinners, based on there combination, on button click a new xml is opened, where an image will be shown based on combination from the spinners.

basically iam facing 2 problems.

1. The button onClickListner() is not working,  well I commented the function and moved ahead
2. The image.setImageResource() is not working logcat says he is unable to start the activity.

so what exactly did I do wrong??

This is the main activity code.. everything before try works perfectly.. but the onclick listner() crashes the code.. but on comment the prg works..

```
try
    {
        /*btn=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button);
        System.out.println(btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {              

            public void onClick(View v) {*/

                if(subtxt.equals("Maths"))
                {
                    if(Integer.parseInt(yeartxt)==1990)
                    {
                        Intent ip = new Intent(MainActivity.this, maths.class);
                        startActivity(ip);
                    }
.
 //the prg executes until start activity perfectly and continues onto maths.class
.

.
```

this is the code in maths.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 ImageView image;
 image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 image.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_maths);
 setContentView(R.layout.physics);
    }
```

all activities are specified in android mainfest.. 
and this is the log cat

```
 02-13 00:29:20.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
 02-13 00:29:20.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
 02-13 00:29:20.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
 02-13 00:29:20.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 02-13 00:29:20.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 02-13 00:29:20.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 02-13 00:29:20.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-13 00:29:20.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 02-13 00:29:20.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 02-13 00:29:20.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 02-13 00:29:20.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 02-13 00:29:20.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1485): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 02-13 00:29:20.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):    at com.example.subjects.maths.onCreate(maths.java:16)
 02-13 00:29:20.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
 02-13 00:29:20.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
 02-13 00:29:20.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
 02-13 00:29:20.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):    ... 11 more
```

so what exactly is the reason for the 2 errors am facing here. ??

***EDIT*** ***ANSWER***

```
1) the on clicklistner() error can be avoided by declaring all variables globally in mainactivity.java
2) the image.setImageResource() should be given after setcontentview..
```

that's all there is.

Comment: which is your 16 line in com.example.subjects.maths.onCreate method ?

Comment: (for onClick ) did you add `maths` activity to your manifest file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go wrong over here: first `setContentView(R.layout.physics)` and after get `image` `oncreate()` method:

You should format like below:

```
 image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 image.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_maths);
 setContentView(R.layout.physics);
```

Replace this with

```
 setContentView(R.layout.physics);
 image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 image.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_maths);
```

Comment: thanks man... solved the problem... :) but what abt onclicklistner?? whats its problem..

Comment: it was commented as it would crash the code.. cant figure out what its problem is.. the log cat wen code is active has vbeen posted

Comment: @Alvin try t post your all code. Without i cant judge where is error occurred?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47383/discussion-between-alvin-and-m-d)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first set the view and then use the resources. Move the line `setContentView(R.layout.physics);` to the top.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.physics);
 ImageView image;
 image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 image.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_maths);

    }
```

Comment: thanks man... solved the problem... :) but what abt onclicklistner?? whats its problem..

Comment: Try running the app with the onclicklistner code. What error do you get?

Comment: The log cat details are no way related to `onclicklistner` You must be using SoundPool or media files somewhere, and that's what is causing the error. Please update the post with the entire log cat message. Don't filter it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Change this code**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
ImageView image;
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_maths);
setContentView(R.layout.physics);
}
```

**to**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.physics);
ImageView image;
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_maths);

}
```